# Rails, validate has_many through association with attribute value of children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :game_accounts
    has_many :favorite_game_accounts, through: :game_account_favorites, source: :game_account
end

class GameAccount < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :favorite_users, through: :game_account_favorites, source: :user
end

class GameAccountFavorite < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :game_account

    validates_presence_of :user, :game_account
    validates_uniqueness_of :user, scope: :game_account_id
end
```

This means that `User` can have his own `GameAccounts` and other `Users` can add them to favorites.

I have added `scope` in order to prevent one user to have multiple favorites of the same `GameAccount`. However, there is one problem. User can add to favorite **his own GameAccount**. How to prevent user adding his own `GameAccount` to favorites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that there is any built-in Rails validation for you case, so I'd suggest writing your own custom one.

In your particular case, you can verify on `GameAccountFavorite` instance, that `game_account.user_id` isn't equal to `user.id`.

There's plenty of ways of [performing custom validation in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations)